# Bad handling of PHP sessions variables?

Tags: php, security, session

I'm currently using the following code in my cms to check if visitor is logged in as admin so that he can edit the current page:

```
if($_SESSION['admin']=="1")
{
        echo "<a href="foobar/?update">edit</a>";
}
```

But I'm worried that the code is unsafe. Can't $_session variables easily be modified by the user?

What would be a safer practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's a good way to do it. The user can't modify the $_SESSION global, unless he has access to your server. Remember to **stay away from client-side cookies**.

To make it even more safe, a good way is to store the IP-adress and check that it stays the same between every request.

Comment: Thanks! Checking IP sounds good; I reckon you should store the ip directly after session_start(), e.g.:
session_start()
$_SESSION["visitorIp"] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
Right?

Comment: Checking the IP address is a bad idea actually - there are plenty of organisations with proxies that mean a user can appear to have several IP addresses. This also used to affect all AOL users - not sure if it still does.

Comment: @AquinasTub: Not quite. You aren't checking the visitorIp, just writing it. It should look more like if isset($_SESSION['username']) {/* check user ip */ if ($_SESSION['visitorIp'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {session_unset(); header("Location: /login"); exit();} } /* Set user IP */ $_SESSION['visitorIp'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Comment: @Greg: No, it's not if you require proper Cookies AND the ip. It would only be unsafe if you used it as a single authentication factor.

Comment: With IP checking, how would you handle multiple IPs? Doesn't that mean that a user can't stay logged in at multiple computers? Or worse: at the same computer if their ISP gives them different IPs each time?

Comment: @Dinah: Not if you create a separate session for each ip.  I actually implement IP checking authentication (with others) on my PHP system, and I can be logged in from as many computers/IPs as I want.  Each system/ip has its own session.

Comment: I would check to see if the user agent string has changed, and if so, call session_regenerate_id()

Answer (score 3):

The code is OK, you're just showing a link. Just make sure that your UPDATE script is protected as well.

Answer (score 1):

Session variables should be safe enough once your coding is secure.

Also, use the follow instead. Stops mistakes with == 
Probably should also use true too as it is a lot quicker than string comparisons.

```
if( "1" === $_SESSION['admin'] )
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` variables can not be set by the user. The code is therefore perfectly fine, although you would usually ask your user backend (typically just a table users, sometimes LDAP) about the current user's privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I found this presentation about session security

- http://talks.php.net/show/phpworks2004-php-session-security/

It explains how to avoid:

- Session fixation.
- Session hijacking.

Also the slide with more information has some really goods links

- http://talks.php.net/show/phpworks2004-php-session-security/18

Answer (score 0):

This code is no longer safe:

```
if mypage.php contains this code:

session_start();
$_SESSION['admin']==1;
echo "<a href='http://the.link-to-your-page.php' target='_blank'>link</a>";
```

If the link is clicked, the session admin as 1 will be carried to your page and the edit button will be appeared.

safest way is to set a token (this is a very simple step) right after login is authenticated. 
e.g `$token = sh512($var.....); $_SESSION['token']=$token;`

on top of every page put something like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){ die('Access Denied');}
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ die('Access Granted');}
```

first check the token carry in the SESSION and then Check the user ID, including level of permissions for users. This is just a simple approach, put more fingerprint scan code at the beginning to make it complex to intercept sessionid.